# Is it possible to create a menu item with first argument as wildcard?

Tags: routes

I have created a menu item using hook_menu() with the following structure.Unfortunately, when i access the given link, it returns not found error?
Can anyone give a solution for this?

```
$items['%/doctors/department/%/%'] = array(  
  'title'=>'Search a Doctor by Department  - Thumbay Hospital',
  'page arguments' => array(0,3,4),
  'page callback'=>'location_find_doctor_by_dept',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) docs:

> Note that wildcards may not be used as the first component.

So by design, no, it's not possible.